# Variations (Cartesian) Product on the fly like on the Shopify

Tags: jquery, vue.js, shopify, cartesian-product

I want to display a list of all possible combinations (cartesian) on an element when my inputs (attributes) are being entered. It has to be realtime (on the fly).
I have a code to generate the cartesians, but I am struggling on displaying them while changing the inputs. Each input must generate it's additional combinations and display the additionals rather replacing the entire section.

This process is seamless on the Shopify, I want to replicate the same function on my JS appliation.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs to know the answer ;[Cartesian](https://github.com/ehmicky/fast-cartesian) use this repository for vue3. It's the best way I found and it's pretty fast and reliable.